# Do I need to sister this ceiling joist?

Tags: plumbing, ceiling, joists

A plumber came to push my DWV pipe back so I could decreased my soffit/bulkhead. In the process, he cut a bit into one of my 2x8 ceiling joists. Not ideal. Wondering if I need to sister the whole joist, or if I can just glue/screw a sistered 2x8 for a 4 ft run or so.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It depends on the spacing, the span, and what it’s supporting. Is there a living space above the joist? What is the span of the 2x8? How far over to the next joist?

Comment: I’d love to see the other side of the joist. It looks like it’s cut down in about half. Can you post a picture?

Comment: Please add two pictures to help clarify things. 1) a bit further back showing the whole joist (putting a tape measure in there so we can see exactly how much has been cut out would be ideal). 2) a picture of the other side of that joist se we can see what's been done there - it does look like there may be some cut away on the other side that we can't see from here.

Comment: See above photos per request

Comment: Ooof... there is a fair bite taken out of the other side of that joist! I realize that a pic may be impossible, but can you give us an idea of how high up that notch goes on the "pipe side"?

Comment: @FreeMan The notch is approximately 4" long and at its highest point, is about 1" high. The span to the next joist is 16" on center. The length of the joist is about 10'. At this point, I'm inclined to try and install a sister, but not sure if I should install a 4'-5' length sister or cut out the drywall and sister the whole beam if I can.

Comment: @jcwkjw20170 Why not answer the first question posed to you? Is there a living space above? (Oh never mind. Who cares?)

Comment: @Lee Sam, apologies, yes there is living space above, you are looking at a toilet flange, so that is the master bathroom

Answer (score 1):

The Code allows a notch of 1/6th the depth of the joist, not 1/4th the depth as noted by @DMoore.

See attached description and figure as noted in IBC Section 2308 and IRC R502.8.

Here’s the diagram showing notches, etc.:

http://www.co.routt.co.us/DocumentCenter/View/61/Notching-and-Boring-Allowances-for-Lumber?bidId=

So, if your joists are 2x8’s and are 7 1/4” tall, you can notch about 1 1/4” maximum and it be looks like it’s significantly more than that.

Comment: Your link should be more specific. It's to an entire search result. Also, I'd estimate that notch as approximately 1-1/4", not significantly more.

Comment: @isherwood  My answer is not from a search. Click on the link and you’ll see a diagram showing all the notches allowed by code. You should direct your comment to DMoore, who makes no reference to any code.

Comment: No. The URL is clearly a Google search as you can see by its structure. _You_ may get particular results, but they're different from everyone else's. You need to link to the thing you're describing, not the search that presents it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Need to? No.

Even if that notch slightly exceeds what's allowable by code, it's near the end and it's just one. Your floor system is interconnected to spread load, so unless you have a bearing wall or an aquarium above it's not really a concern.

Code is written for worst-case situations, such as severe modification and modification of multiple members. This isn't going to cause your house to cave in. Heck, zillions of joists have been installed with *knots* bigger than that.

I will say, though, that a really good plumber would've made a cleaner cut to avoid removing excess material, and would've discussed any framing modifications with you (as the general contractor). It would've chafed me a bit to see this in my house.

Answer (score -1):

The notch at the bottom is fine - not even close to hitting code requirements... which gives you 1/4 joist and that is the best place to notch - near the edge.

You get 1/3 the joist height for holes.   I don't think yours meets that even if you add the inch shaved off on the bottom.   You could sister something over the hole but for something that small your sister would be for aesthetics as the joist is not going to feel any tension near the end like that.

Comment: So you think it’s ok to notch the “tension” edge of a joist or beam?

Comment: I get it with the notch. How about the drill hole above it in combination with the notch?

Comment: @LeeSam - yes.   code says 1/4th... this is like 1/10th.   I notch more than 1/4 and buy braces ALL THE TIME.   The edge is the safest place to notch.

Comment: @HoneyDo - good call, added wording for that.   It is really too small to even deal with, guessing 2.5-3 inches.

Comment: Doesn’t that joist look like it’s been cut down to about one-half thickness?

Comment: Initially, I agreed, in principle, with the assertion in this answer, @LeeSam, but with the updated pics, it looks like it's been whittled down to a thin edge at the bottom - you're probably right on track with your 1/2" assessment! There's a fair chunk missing on the other side, too.

Comment: I don't see any electrical staples....

Comment: It is correct to say the tension is negligible near the support end, but how about shear transfer over the reduced effective area? I am not a wood guy, but I think you shall check it before assessing it is fine. Also, it would be beneficial to provide the code provisions for others to look into it.

Comment: @DMoore You might want to add something to your answer about installing the brace you mentioned in a comment. That does sound like a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it gave incorrect information about the size of a notch allowed in the joist.

Comment: Yeah, the 1/3 figure is for _holes in the central portion_ as I understand it, not for notches.